# Modify xml element name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to change element name with following statement:

```
SET @myDoc.modify('replace value of (/CustomerInfo)[1] with "Customer"')
```

from
<**CustomerInfo**>
    <ID>1</ID>
</**CustomerInfo**>
to
<**Customer**>
    <ID>1</ID>
</**Customer**>
But failed. So how can i change it just in sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried following sql:
select @myDoc=(
select @myDoc.query('/CustomerInfo/node()')
for xml raw('Customer'),type)
I guess it solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to select the values with .query or .nodes into a resultset that will render into the XML you want using [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-grace method:
Convert xml to varchar, then replace it.